# Functions return empty arrays on the 2nd and subsequent loops

Tags: python

I want this script to output 3 arrays however, `n=2,3` return empty arrays.

It is correctly identifying the line numbers but just not writing the last 2 arrays.
`testdata` and `measure_pnt` are passed in correctly via the defined instances.

There is an issue somewhere between the functions `extract_sensordata_Ntimes` and `extract_sensordata` but I cannot identify it.

```
class unv_processing():

    class vrbls:
        def __init__(self, extracted_data=None, timeH=None):
            self.extracted_data = extracted_data
            self.timeH = timeH

    def __init__(self):
        self.EO = {1: self.vrbls(), 2: self.vrbls(), 3: self.vrbls()}

    def read_testdata(self, testdata):
        self.no_samples = 202422  
        self.alldata = pd.read_csv(testdata, 
                                   sep='delimiter',header=None)
        return self.alldata

    def extract_sensordata_Ntimes(self, measure_pnt):
        def reader(n):
            self.EO[n].extracted_data = self.extract_sensordata(
                measure_pnt[n])
        for i in (1, 2, 3):
            reader(i)
        return

    def extract_sensordata(self, measure_pnt):
        l1 = None
        for c in range(len(self.alldata.iloc[:, 0])):
            if self.alldata.iloc[c, 0] == measure_pnt:
                l1 = c+11
                print(f'unv line number {l1}')
                break
        if l1:
            self.extract_data = pd.DataFrame(
                self.alldata.iloc[l1:self.no_samples, 0]).to_numpy()
            self.extract_data = np.array([i[0].split()                                        
                                             for i in 
                                             self.extract_data]).astype(
                                             'float64').ravel()
        return print(self.extract_data)

def main(arg_mod):
s = unv_processing()
s.read_testdata(arg_mod.testdata)
s.extract_sensordata_Ntimes(arg_mod.measure_pnt)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
unv line number 29
[0.0128353 0.0324985 0.0612448 ... 0.        0.        0.       ]
unv line number 202436
[]
unv line number 404843
[]
```

Comment: There are some indention problem in your code block and makes it hard to understand your code

Comment: I couldnt find a way to use tab correcly. I will use spacebar

Comment: Sounds like a cursor issue. Have you looked into that?